# How do Smart Businesses Transform to "Work From Home"

Tags: internal-transfer, customer-service, business, transition, work-from-home

Heres a smart businesses approach on transforming its customer success team to working remotely. What are your thoughts on it? Are these enough steps taken. Do you think it can be as productive. Share your thoughts.

[image]

https://www.mindmeister.com/1361793354?t=3lw1wI7wrj